# Why am I getting a 'NoneType' type error on data that is not a 'NoneType'?

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, nonetype

I have a series of functions that take a pandas dataframe, cleanse the data and then send it to sqlite db.

The following function is creating the error:

```
def send_to_db(df, event_name):

    print df.describe()

    table_names = {
        'Video Played': 'video_played',
        'Item Information Click': 'item_info_click',
        'Faved': 'faved',
        'Add to Cart': 'add_to_cart',
        'Tap to Replay': 'replay'
    }

    print table_names.get(event_name)

    con = db.connect('/Users/metersky/code/mikmak/vid_score/test.db')
    df.to_sql(table_names.get(event_name), con, flavor='sqlite', if_exists='append')
    con.close()
```

The error I get is `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

This is weird to me for two reasons:

1) `print df.describe()` gives me the proper pandas output, meaning the data is not `None` at that point in the function

2)  The data gets sent to the sqlite database, which I verified.  So this mean that the data isn't `None` there either.

Why am I getting this error and when is my data turning into `None`?

---

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fetch_data.py", line 139, in <module>
    df, event_name = send_to_db(df, event_name)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

This is how I call the functions:

```
for event in event_types:
    print event
    df, event_name = get_data(start_date, end_date, event)

    print "*********" + event_name + " data retrieved"

    df, event_name = data_cleanse(df, event_name)

    print  "*********" + event_name + " data cleansed"

    df, event_name = send_to_db(df, event_name)

    print  "*********" + event_name + " data sent to db"
```

Comment: Please provide a Traceback so we can clearly see the error and where it's occurring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are **not** returning anything from your function but are expecting a tuple of 2-items `(df, event_name)`:

When you call your function:

```
df, event_name = send_to_db(df, event_name)
```

You are expecting to get back a tuple of 2-items.

However your function implicitly returns `None` (*because there is no non-empty `return` statement*)

You need to modify your function to add:

```
return df, event_name
```

**Update:** If you *really* don't need the return value(s) from your function then don't call your function with anything on the left-hand side of the assignment statement. This implies tuple unpacking from the result of your function. Just call your function like this:

```
send_to_db(df, event_name)
```

See: [Python Packing and Unpacking](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples#Packing_and_Unpacking) and [Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) where it says:

> This is called, appropriately enough, sequence unpacking and works for
>   any sequence on the right-hand side. Sequence unpacking requires the
>   list of variables on the left to have the same number of elements as
>   the length of the sequence. Note that multiple assignment is really
>   just a combination of tuple packing and sequence unpacking.

Comment: I need to do this even though I don't need anything returned?  I just need the data sent to the db and then the for-loop to move onto the next event that i need to process.

Comment: **That's how** you are calling your function. Yes

Comment: @Meepl: No, of course if you don't need anything returned, you don't need to do this… but then you can't _use_ the return value that doesn't exist. Just call it as `send_to_db(df, event_name)` instead of `df, event_name = send_to_db(df, event_name)`.